# LibGDX Box2D circle vibrates when hitting ground

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d

When restitution is greater than 0 the object vibrates once it bounces instead of stopping normal.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried giving it a density when creating it? Something like `fixtureDef.density = 1.0f;` should help it come to a rest.

Setting its linear damping might also help.

Comment: I tried giving it a density, it still happens. Maybe give me a small example of code on the linear damping and if it works I can mark you as the answer. Should the ground have a density also?

Comment: The ground shouldn't need to have density, as far as I know. `bodyDef.linearDamping = 1.0f` should give it linear damping.